# Redirect subdomain traffic to different ports on tomcat8

Tags: tomcat8

How do I set up tomcat so that http://a.site.com points to X.X.X.X:8010 and http://b.site.com points to 1X.X.X.X:8020 (i.e. two different sites on the same box with different ports)? The godaddy DNS guys tell me that both the subdomains a and b must both point to X.X.X.X and cannot specify port and that I should be able to manage that on the server. How this can be done? Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

DNS records can't specify a port, so you'll need to configure some sort of redirection that listens on port 80 (Because you are using HTTP).

In Apache Tomcat you can do this with seperate virtual hosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName a.site.com
  Redirect / http://X.X.X.X:8010
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName b.site.com
  Redirect / http://X.X.X.X:8020
</VirtualHost>
```